# Spring Boot Actuators only exposing limited endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to expose additional actuator endpoints in my Spring Boot 2.3 service. Attempting to add endpoints such as the prometheus and metrics for monitoring. But for some reason, the exposed endpoints are locked to the default loggers,health,info.

For some background, within the org, there is a parent Spring dependency which automatically brings all of the Spring essentials, as well as some generic code useful within the org. I use this dependency in many of my other projects and was able to expose these additional actuator endpoints successfully. However, in this project with multiple artifacts, I am unable to edit the default exposed actuator endpoints.

Printing the `configurableEnvironment` post init always shows the exposure property as follows

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include = loggers,health,info
```

This is after trying to override this property to an expanded list (loggers,health,info,Prometheus,metrics) using below methods:

- Enabling specific endpoint via `management.endpoint.metrics.enabled: true`
- Specifying these values in application.yaml
- Passing this as a Command line argument `Dmanagement.endpoints.web.exposure.include=loggers,health,info,prometheus,metrics`
- Using `mvn dependency:tree` To exclude any transitive actuator dependencies

I don’t believe its due to the org’s parent pom, likely due to another dependency we are using. But due to the size of this project, it is quite hard to remove dependencies to test. Is there any way to track down where these properties are set. Or perhaps additional ways to force exposure of the additional endpoints I want?

——

Actuator config

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: metrics,prometheus,info,health,logging
  endpoint:
    env:
      enabled: true
    metrics:
      enabled: true
    info:
      enabled: true
    health:
      enabled: true
      show-details: always
    beans:
      enabled: true
    caches:
      enabled: true
    threaddump:
      enabled: true
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
```

Actuator info

```
{"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:9050/actuator","templated":false},"health":{"href":"http://localhost:9050/actuator/health","templated":false},"health-path":{"href":"http://localhost:9050/actuator/health/{*path}","templated":true},"info":{"href":"http://localhost:9050/actuator/info","templated":false},"loggers":{"href":"http://localhost:9050/actuator/loggers","templated":false},"loggers-name":{"href":"http://localhost:9050/actuator/loggers/{name}","templated":true}}}
```

Comment: Dependencies won't set the value for that property. `-Dmanagement.endpoints.web.exposure.include=loggers,health,info,prometheus,metrics` isn't a command line attribute but a system property, which when placed in the wrong place (after the `-jar <your jar>`) doesn't do anything. `--management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=loggers,health,info,prometheus,metrics` is a command line argument.

Comment: @deinum tried your approach but get an error on startup instead. 
Unrecognized option: —management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=loggers,health,info,prometheus,metrics
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Comment: I stated (i thought clearly) that when it is **after** the `-jar` in your commandline/script it is wrong. If it is before that (basically following the `java` command) it is in the correct position.

Comment: Made sure that was the case (all options in front, jar at the end), but it still errored out.

Comment: I must be unclear... When it is `-D` it needs to go **before** the `-jar`... When it is `--management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=loggers,health,info,prometheus,metrics` it needs to go **after** `-jar <your-jar>`...

Comment: @deinum, apologies mis read, but attempted putting the —management… **after** the -jar as well with no effect

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks some background, like your pom.xml or build.gradle files and full application.yml config.

I will go through the basic steps, which you may have missed.

Firstly, please make sure that you've included the Prometheus dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also, don't forget that some metrics require the AOP dependency (like custome timers, for example):

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

To enable the Prometheus metrics exposure, you should specify such configuration in your application.yml file (it seems like you did it correctly, but let's list it here for the full picture):

```js
management:
  endpoints:
    web.exposure.include: health, info, prometheus
```

To verify that the Prometheus endpoints were exposed, please use the GET request to this URL: `http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus`

If those steps don't help you resolve your issue, please add more details to your question.

Comment: Hey @alexander-golovnya thanks for this, but everything you have mentioned has been attempted with no success. I am not at liberty to share the pom.xml due to org rules, but there are anyways way too many dependencies both private and public within that file for it to be worth pasting here. What other kind of details could I add to help here?

Comment: Sure, it's understandable. Could you please then check than that you included the Prometheus dependency to your pom.xml and post the response from http://localhost:8080/actuator. Besides that, please include your full configs under the 'management' prefix

Comment: Added to question if you don’t mind having a look!